# Different 404 pages in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've made a custom 404 page for Laravel. So far it's working. However, when a user tries to access a director in the public folder of laravel `application/public` (not `application/storage/app/public`) it gives the default 404 page:

[image]

This is what it looks like with my custom 404 page (notice the URL):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first one is direct access to file/folder from the server.

The second is handled by the `Laravel` routing system.

So they are different.

Comment: How do I make a 404 file for the file/folder from the server?